# Magento Attribute Sort Order in Configurable Product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, attributes

I need help with the following:

In Magento I have created a configurable product and assigned some simple products to it. They have an individual attribute set with individual, numeric attributes that I have created.

One attribute is for example "length". This attribute has the following values:
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20

If I open the drop-down menu on the article details page, the values get displayed like that:
10,12,14,16,18,20,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Thus, it seems that the attributes are saved as text (alphanumerical?) and not as numbers (numerical)?!

I need some advice on how I can change that. I have tried to work with "Input Validation for Store Owner" in "Manage Attributes", but that doesn't work. Is there f.e. any field in my database where I can simply switch the way my attributes are saved/displayed?

I have created many products and attributes, thus I don't want to re-create all of them again, if not necessary.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since you asked and might be you have already found a solution to it. I am just writing so that anyone coming on this page for the same problem does not have to go thru the same pain what i went thru.

When you create the attribute(length), you would have created the options (like 3/4/5.. etc) create the sort of that options in the attribute section and they will sort as per your requirement.